# How to find time difference in seconds between 2 dates in bash?

Tags: bash

I currently have the variables below and want to know how much time elapsed in seconds. So CURRENT_TIME - TEST_START

```
TEST_START=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
sleep 4
CURRENT_TIME=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

I tried below, but keep getting illegal action

```
START_IN_SECONDS=$(date --date "$(TEST_START)" +%s)
```

This is in Mac.

Comment: Use `${variable}` not `$(variable)`

Comment: `$(...)` is for doing command substitution, like when you assign to `TEST_START`.

Comment: i tried that as well

Comment: Why can't you just use timestamps instead of date strings? Or at least use std date string format.

Answer (score 2):

First, the syntax for expanding variables is `$variable` or `${variable}`, not `$(variable)`.

Second, `date` doesn't know how to parse dates that are in `%d/%m/%Y` format. When the date uses slashes, it expects it to be `%m/%d/%Y`. So change your first two lines to use the correct format.

```
TEST_START=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
sleep 4
CURRENT_TIME=$(date '+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
START_IN_SECONDS=$(date --date "$TEST_START" +%s)
CURRENT_IN_SECONDS=$(date --date "$CURRENT_TIME" +%s)
diff=$((CURRENT_IN_SECONDS - START_IN_SECONDS))
echo $diff
```

Of course, you could just set the `xxx_IN_SECONDS` variables directly with `+%s` instead of parsing formatted dates:

```
START_IN_SECONDS=$(date +%s)
sleep 4
CURRENT_IN_SECONDS=$(date +%s)
```

Comment: I'm getting "date: illegal option -- -", I think it might be because im on a mac

Comment: Mac has BSD `date`, you're trying to use the syntax for GNU `date`.

Comment: BSD date doesn't have a flexible date parser. Use `man date` to see its syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Time Arithmetic

TIME1=05:36:11
TIME2=06:46:00

# Convert the times to seconds from the Epoch
SEC1=`date +%s -d ${TIME1}`
SEC2=`date +%s -d ${TIME2}`

# Use expr to do the math, let's say TIME1 was the start and TIME2 was the finish
DIFFSEC=`expr ${SEC2} - ${SEC1}`

echo Start ${TIME1}
echo Finish ${TIME2}

echo Took ${DIFFSEC} seconds.

# And use date to convert the seconds back to something more meaningful
echo Took `date +%H:%M:%S -ud @${DIFFSEC}`
```

Output:

```
Start 05:36:11
Finish 06:46:00
Took 4189 seconds.
Took 01:09:49
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this and it does not work. I get "date: illegal time format".

Comment: I think it might be an issue because im using a Mac